# Ajax отправка запроса на страницу несколько раз

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Здравствуйте!
Имеется проблема, создал я значит ajax запрос, форму для него и соответсвенно отдельный файл для запроса, все работает только 1 раз без перезагрузки страницы. А нужно чтобы при открытии страницы запрос ajax мог срабатывать несколько раз без перезагрузки. Я конечно понимаю что скорее всего это было бы проще сделать через javascript, но в данном случае я хочу попробовать реализовать это через ajax
Вот код который я использую для реализации.
Запрос:

```
function Send() {
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'ajax.php',
                data:{name1:"$_POST[name1]", name2:"$_POST[name2]", text:"$_POST[text]"},
                response:'text',
                success: function (result) {
                    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '';
                    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = result;
                }
            });
        }
```

Форма:

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="form">
        <input type="text" name="name1" placeholder="SecureCode 1">
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Write a text">
        <input type="text" name="name2" placeholder="SecureCode 2">
        <input type="button" value="Tap and get md5 hash" onclick="Send();">
    </form>
```

Ответ:

```
if($_POST['name1'] != 0 or $_POST['text'] != 0 or $_POST['name2'] != 1) {
    header("Content-type: text/txt; charset=UTF-8");
    echo 'Введены не все данные';
} else {
    header("Content-type: text/txt; charset=UTF-8");
    $test = md5($_POST['name1'].md5($_POST['text']).$_POST['name2']);
    echo $test; 
}
```

Comment: очень так не ясно, что вы хотите?  что бы при загрузке страницы запрос несколько раз отсылал в обработчик пустой $_post? Ведь так и будет.

Answer (score 0):

Ммм пробуйте добавить евент на кнопку через jquery 
Пример :
Форма:

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="form">
    <input type="text" name="name1" placeholder="SecureCode 1">
    <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Write a text">
    <input type="text" name="name2" placeholder="SecureCode 2">
    <input id="get_hash" type="button" value="Tap and get md5 hash">
</form>
```

Евент :

```
$("#get_hash").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'ajax.php',
        data:{name1:"$_POST[name1]", name2:"$_POST[name2]", text:"$_POST[text]"},
        response:'text',
        success: function (result) {
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '';
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = result;
        }
    });
})
```